# SQL - select by status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting data from sql table (T-SQL) that looks like:

```
ID | Name | Status | Date 
1  | Tom  | 1      |20140101
2  | Tom  | 2      |20140301
3  | Dan  | 1      |20140301
4  | Tom  | 3      |20140302
5  | Dan  | 3      |20140304
6  | Sam  | 2      |20140405
7  | Tom  | 4      |20140406
```

Need to select all users with status 3, but if user got status 4 or grater it shouldn't be displayed.

In this example only Dan with ID 5 should be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM T 
WHERE NAME NOT IN (SELECT NAME FROM T WHERE STATUS >= 4)
AND STATUS = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM USERS U1 
WHERE 
    Status = 3 
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM 
        USERS U2 
        WHERE 
            Status > 3 
            AND U1.Name = U2.Name
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE status = 3
```

will only return user with status that is equal to 3

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73d79/1)

You just need to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from t t1
where t1.status = 3 and not exists 
    (select 1 from t t2 where status > 3 and t1.Name = t2.Name)
```